# is_tax() not working in Widget Logic

Tags: widgets

I've tried every which way to get a widget to show up on all the taxonomy archive pages of my custom taxonomy via Widget Logic plugin, and it just won't work.

- URL: `baseurl.com/podcast-category/food`
- Taxonomy name: `podcast-category`
- Category 1: `food`

Tried:
`is_tax()`, `is_tax('podcast-category')`, `is_tax('podcast-category','food')`

Nothing. Very perplexed.

Comment: Please can you post the code you are using

Comment: Please ask your question to plugin developers. Third-party plugins are off-topic here.

Comment: are you using any custom query in the taxonomy archive template?

Comment: Thanks Max, I've seen others posting about widgets, esp this one in this forum. If you're not keen on replying, that's fine - tho you did spend some time editing my question only to tell me not to ask it.

Michael - I'm not. 

Zezo - the code I've tried is in the above description.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're actually looking for is_post_type_archive($my_custom_post_type)

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive

Comment: Thanks Melissa, wish I did. is_post_type_archive() is the archive of my CPT, and that works fine with the widget. is_tax('taxonomy-name') pulls the taxonomy. It's like saying is_category('cat-name') for posts.

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the classes on the page's body tag where you want the widget to display? It will give a clue to what the right value is for your is_tax function.